# Connect to Samba Drive Remotely

Tags: samba

I have 137, 138, 139, and 445 port forwarded and ufw allow for all those ports but i cant seem to connect to my drive smb from outside my network. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect from inside your network?

You can try an nmap scan from outside to see if the port forwardings are 
working properly.

install via

```
sudo apt install nmap
```

run scan via

```
sudo nmap -A your-public-ip-address
```

Than you can try to connect via smbclient using this command:

install via

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

(-L)ist shares via

```
smbclient -L your-public-ip-address
```